# Javascript scrollTo() the window.find() position

Tags: javascript

I want search text into a scrollabe div and scroll to the founded element, like the Search feature of the browser (CTRL + F). This code works just for the first 3/4 clicks, after the scroll position is totally wrong. What I'm doing wrong...?

```js
function windowFind() {
   const input = document.getElementById('input');
    if ( window.find(input.value, false) ) {
        const s = window.getSelection();
        const oRange = s.getRangeAt(0);
        const oRect = oRange.getBoundingClientRect();
        const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
        const scrollTo = oRect.top - wrapper.offsetTop;
        wrapper.scrollTo({ top: scrollTo });
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="stackoverflow"><button type="button" onclick="windowFind()">Search</button>

<div id="wrapper" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block; overflow: auto">
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 1</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 2</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 3</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 4</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 5</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 6</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 7</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 8</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 9</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 10</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 11</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 12</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 13</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 14</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 15</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 16</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 17</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 18</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 19</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 20</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 21</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 22</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, your forget to compute the actual scrollTop of your wrapper.

So after the first click your scrollTo append to the default scroll so to 0 then you get negative and erroned values

Adding the `wrapper.scrollTop` to your `const scrollTo` is what you searchin for :)

```js
function windowFind() {
   const input = document.getElementById('input');
   const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    if ( window.find(input.value, false) ) {
        const s = window.getSelection();
        const oRange = s.getRangeAt(0);
        const oRect = oRange.getBoundingClientRect();
        const scrollTo =( oRect.top - wrapper.offsetTop)+wrapper.scrollTop;
        wrapper.scrollTo({ top: scrollTo });
    }
}

//Can be shorten to
windowFindShort = () => {
  const e = document.getElementById("input"),
    t = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  if (window.find(e.value, !1)) {
    const e = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    t.scrollTo({
      top: e.top - t.offsetTop + t.scrollTop
    })
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="stackoverflow"><button type="button" onclick="windowFind()">Search</button>
<button type="button" onclick="windowFindShort()">Search (short verison)</button>
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block; overflow: auto">
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 1</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 2</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 3</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 4</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 5</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 6</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 7</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 8</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 9</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 10</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 11</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 12</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 13</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 14</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 15</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 16</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 17</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 18</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 19</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 20</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow 21</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow 22</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block; background-color: lightgray;">stackoverflow</div>
   <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; display: block">stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```